# How to ilterate with recursive function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

```js
function numberSum(num) {

  var str = num.toString();
  var arrNum = str.split('').map(Number);//arrNum = [1, 2, 3];

  //For-looping
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    result = result + arrNum[i];
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(numberSum(22222)); // 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10
```

I did this with For-looping and then iterate it. The question is, how do i did the same but with Recursive Function?

Comment: See [General way to convert a loop (while/for) to recursion or from a recursion to a loop?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a)

Comment: by recursively calling a function

Answer (score 2):

You could use only the first element for addition and call the function with the rest of the array again.

In this case, a check is made for the length, this returns either `0` if the array has no items or the item count, then a shift is made which returns the first item of the array. Additionaly the function is called again with the reduced array.

> ```
> function iter(array) {
>     return array.length && array.shift() + iter(array);
>     //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 exit condition,
>     //                                                  if zero, return zero, 
>     //                                                  otherwise return the
>     //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  iteration part
>     //                                                  return the first value and
>     //                                                  call recursion again
> }
> ```

```js
function numberSum(v) {
    function iter(array) {
        return array.length && array.shift() + iter(array);
    }

    return iter(v.toString().split('').map(Number));
}

console.log(numberSum(22222)); // 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For the input you have (22222) your function is a practical solution.  If you want a function that takes a number and adds itself together a certain number of times you can simply do this...

```
function sums(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
sums(2, 5);
//=> 10
```

But if you really require an example of a recursive function to do this the following will achieve the same result...

```
var num = 2;
var iterate = 5;

function sums(n, count, total) {
    if (count === 0) {
        return total;
    } else {
        return sums(n, --count, total+n);
    }
}
console.log(sums(num, iterate, 0));
//=> 10
```

Hope that helped. :)

(See this [blog post on JavaScript recursion](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/js-recursion.html) by integralist).